# How can IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()'s go-to implemetation is to return GetEnumerator(), if GetEnumerator() is of diffrent return type?

Tags: c#, generics, ienumerable, return-type, ienumerator

I am trying to understand why something like

```cs
 class Foo : IEnumerable<int>
    {
        public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator()
        {
            //....
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return GetEnumerator();
        }
    }
```

isn't a compiler error. `GetEnumerator()` returns  `IEnumerator<int>` while `IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()` is supposed to return `IEnumerator`, yet it return the generic version which is `IEnumerator<int>`, as it just returns `GetEnumerator();`. So clearly different return types. What am I missing here?

Comment: Please look at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerable-1?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0). The generic `IEnumerable<T>` _implements_ the non-generic `IEnumerable`, so the former is the subtype of the latter.

Comment: Declared as [`public interface IEnumerator<out T> : IDisposable, System.Collections.IEnumerator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerator-1?view=net-5.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As is pointed out in the comments, an `IEnumerator<T>` implements `IEnumerator` so in essence an `IE<T>` "is a" `IE`. It's probably easier to see if we do this, which is fine:

```
class Foo : IEnumerable<int>
{
    private IEnumerator<int> x;
    
    public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return x;
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return x;
    }
}
```

It doesn't work if we change the type of X to IEnumerator:

```
class Foo : IEnumerable<int>
{
    private IEnumerator x;
    
    public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return x;
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return x;
    }
}
```

Because while an `IE<T>` is-a `IE`, it doesn't mean an `IE` is-a `IE<T>`, for similar reasons that e.g. a "string is-a object" but not necessarily a "object is-a string"

Had it been this:

```
class Lion:IAnimal{}

class Zoo{
  Lion GetLion() { }
  IAnimal GetAnimal() { return GetLion(); }
}
```

..you wouldn't even have questioned it :)